# Call a function in an activity from SimpleOnGestureListener

Tags: android, methods, call

I have a main activity with custom canvas:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        CustomCanvas c = new CustomCanvas(this);
        c.requestFocus();
        cll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.CLL);
        cll.addView(c);
    }

    public void qwerty(String w) {
        ....
        TextView abc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextViewabc);
        abc.setText(w);
        ....
    }
```

Inside CustomCanvas, I have a GestureDetector with SimpleOnGestureListener.
I want to call qwerty() from the methods of SimpleOnGestureListener (such as onSingleTapConfirmed)

Is this possible? If not is there another way of doing so?
Thanks

**....EDIT..... (more info)**

GestureDetector is an object in my CustomCanvas

```
public class CustomCanvas extends View {

    GestureDetector gd;
    ...

    public CustomCanvas(final Context context) {
        super(context);

        gd = new GestureDetector(getContext(), new SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            ....
            //  I also use getScrollX() and getScrollY() in some of the methods here
        });
    }

    ....

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return gd.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

Comment: show us `GestureDetector` also. is this in the same class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got two options. Either you implement the SimpleOnGestureListener in the Activity and set it to the CustomCanvas or you pass the Activity to the CustomCanavas so you can call qwerty() on it from the listener inside the CustomCanvas class.

UPDATE

```
public class CustomCanvas extends View {

    GestureDetector gd;
    YourActivity mYourActivity;
    ...

    public CustomCanvas(final Context context) {
        super(context);

        gd = new GestureDetector(getContext(), new SimpleOnGestureListener() {                   
              public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY){
                  // this implementation makes no sense 
                  if(mYourActivity != null){
                     mYourActivity.qwerty(); 
                  }    
              }    
        });
    }

    public setActivity(YourActivity activity){
         mYourActivity = activity;
    }
}
```

In you Activity class you have to pass the activity to the CustomCanvas.

```
public class YourActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        CustomCanvas c = new CustomCanvas(this);

        // pass the activity to the canvas
        c.setActivity(this);

        c.requestFocus();
        cll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.CLL);
        cll.addView(c);
    }

    public void qwerty(String w) {
        ....
        TextView abc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextViewabc);
        abc.setText(w);
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, do you only implement the CustomCanvas class to override the SimpleOnGestureListener?

Comment: Yes. I override the onScroll, onFling, onDown and onSingleTapConfirmed methods

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot for taking the time to write out the code.
Really appreciate it ;)